# hadoop HDFS blcok size considerations

Tags: hadoop

Can someone tell me for setting the HDFS block size, which of the following considerations is least important.

1. Amount of memory on the namenode
2. Number of namenodes.
3. Number of files that will be stored in HDFS
4. size of typical files that will be stored in HDFS
5. disk capacity of the namenode.

Answer (score 1):

I think important are:
1. Amount of memory on the namenode - more memory means you can allow more blocks, making them smaller. 
2. There is always one namenode. Secondary namenode does not affect scalability. 
3. The more big files you want to store, the bigger blocks you need. 
4. Making block size much more then typical file size makes little sense. In other words - if your typical files are dozens of MB - block size doez not matter. 
5. Usually does not matter since NameNode store everything in memory, and, usually disk is much larger.

I would tell that bigger block size is better in most cases, since you gain NameNode memory, you reduce number of map tasks with thier overhead, and if there are enough files to process - you can employ all your task trackers in any case.